# How to convert week and year in a separate columns to full date in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two text columns with week number (1-52) and year. I would like to convert that to one column with full date starting from Sun, i.e. 52 2022 convert to 12/25/2022. Is it possible in Redshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The to_date() function takes strings and converts them to dates.  See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html

The format string can work with year and workweek values.  See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html

Is this not working or not working as expected?